# Time attendance algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I've recently started to work on Time attendance  software. People are using cards to check in and check out, but sometimes they check out before they check in and then some of them realize they made mistake and check in again. sometimes they check in instead of check out. I wrote an application that creates report and everything works fine when mistakes are simple, but sometimes people are just people and they check in for example 15 times.

I know my question is kinda complex and I doubt there is and answer but I was wondering if there is any algorithm which can determine such mistakes and can create decent report.

thanks in advance.

Comment: In what language? How is your current solution implemented?

Comment: language is not important to me, I was doing it with PHP but I can change to any language, at this moment I'm manually tracking mistakes and creating correction code. I know it's not the best solution, but don't know better way atm

Comment: Sounds more like a training issue to me.

Comment: The key to these kind of problems is often to design the system so that it would be very difficult for the users to do any mistakes, and not to try and catch every kind of mistake that could occur because of a badly designed user interface. If you limit the kinds of errors people could possible do you don't have to do as much work and everything would be much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I think really if you are trying to have your software guess what the users intent was then you would need to base it on what the users schedule should be and what their expected check in/out cycle looks like

If its a workplace and the users are punching in their time and they work 8 hour shifts, you could try to be smart and flag checkins 7.5-8.5 hours apart as probably a check in that should have been a check out.  Then you could flag back to back checkins 23+ hours apart as probably a missed check out on the previous shift.  16 hour differences would still probably be impossible to guess because they could be clocking out for a double, or changing their schedule and working an earlier shift the next day.

If this was for a college building you could probably at least say that back to back checkins that occur on separate calendar days were a missed checkout.

Comment: that's very similar to my solution, but few days ago client called me and told me that one of his workers was working for like 34 hours... :)

Comment: Again, you can take expected scheduling into account here.  I'm sure that your client has rules about the maximum number of hours that can be worked in a day, I'd guess its 16.  If your client has such a rule, if nothing else you can code your system to stop recording time for anyone who has broken the max threshold and print out a report for every time that happens.

Problems like that aren't likely to be solved with software.  There is nothing to prevent the user from never punching out.  That is a problem that needs to be solved with training and workplace rules.